# My if and elif statements are not executing

Tags: python

I'm attempting to learn python and I've come across a problem with my if and elif statements. I checked for indentation and I checked that my conditions are correct, but for some reason the if and elif statements won't execute. Regardless of if I enter 0,1, or 2 for user nothing happens.

I've tried changing the indentation, but that didn't seem to help. I also tried changing all the statements to just if statements and that yielded no change.

```
while win == False:
    user = input("Is your number: " + str(guess) + "\n")

    if user == 2:
        highRange = guess
        guess = (highRange+lowRange)/2
        counter += 1
    elif user == 1:
        lowRange = guess
        guess = (lowRange + highRange)/2
        counter += 1
    elif user == 0:
        print("I figure it out in " + str(counter) + "tries")
        win = True
```

It is meant to execute what is inside the if and elif statements.

Comment: `input` always returns a string. You need to either compare it to a string, e.g. `== '2'` or call `int()` on your input

Answer (score 1):

The input is always a string, but you're comparing it to an integer.

Instead, you could cast it to an `int` as follows:

```
user = int(input("Is your number: " + str(guess) + "\n"))
```

or:

```
if int(user) == 2:
```

etc.

Now, bear in mind that the user may type something in which we cannot interpret as an integer. So to be safe, we can check for invalid input and request a number if the user entered something else:

```
user = None
while user is None:
    try:
        user = int(input("Is your number: " + str(guess) + "\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number!")
```

A different strategy altogether is to change the right hand side of your comparisons to strings by putting the numbers in quotes like this:

```
if user == '2':
```

Leaving `user` as a string will make doing maths with it more awkward.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about that part. I really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The type of user is string, but your if and elif are compared with integer. That's why it wont work.Try using:

```
user = int(input("Is your number: " + str(guess) + "\n"))
```